# How to force AutoCompleteTextView to update height of drop-down?

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have an `AutoCompleteTextView` in my app that connects to a remote site to fetch suggestions. While suggestions are fetched I show a list of one item saying "searching, please wait". After the request completes, I update the suggestion list adapter and call `notifyDataSetChanged`.

Then the list contents changes to new suggestions (as expected), but somehow the list remains 1 cell in height, so that only the top suggestion is visible. How to force the view to re-calculate the dropdown height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `showDropDown()` forces re-evaluation of the suggestion list height. Unfortunately, it also forces it to show, but for my purposes it was acceptable.